# Open shift Pod CPU and terminating details

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

1. Is there any way to filter only terminating pods or problematic pods in open shift from my master node.
2. Is there any way to find which pod is consuming more CPU from the specific node..from my master in Open shift.

We have tried with few commands but it's not helping much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is there any way to filter only terminating pods or problematic pods
>    in open shift from my master node.

To view pods that are not in running status (Terminating, CrashLoopBackOff etc.) you can use:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces  | grep -Ev '([0-9]+)/\1'
```

or to check pods with only Terminated you can use:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=status.phase=Terminated
```

> 2. Is there any way to find which pod is consuming more CPU from the
>    specific node..from my master in Open shift.

To view pod CPU usage you can install [metrics-server](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/cluster_metrics.html) and check consumption by using:

```
kubectl top pod
```

or

```
oc adm top pod
```

Comment: Thanks for your details
  
 OC adm top pods..will list top cpu usage details with 
 irrespective of node.

1. is there any way to find pod cpu usage for a particular node in open shift..from my master